# Which SKAdNetworkIdentifier's are needed for AdMob SKAdNetwork

Tags: admob, skadnetwork

I am using AdMob in an iOS game and I recently updated it to include the AdMob SKAdNetworkIdentifier in my Info.plist file (because there was a warning in my AdMob account to do so). Google's identifier is:

```
cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork
```

This all seemed to work fine and the warning on my AbMob account page disappeared.

But then a few weeks later I got another warning and when I check this page:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14

it says there are a 32 more SKAdNetworkIdentiers in the "select additional buyers" section which AdMob suggests we also have to include.

I have not updated my game yet and the warning has disappeared anyway, so I don't know wether to add all these extra identifiers or not. It looks like the list is regularly added to (last updated 9 April), so seems a pain to have to keep updating my app with them if that is Google's plan.

I don't use "Mediation". So do I need all these 3rd party ones or just the Google one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't use [AdMob Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediate?hl=da), then you don't need to add other SKAdNetworkIdentifiers. You just need to add the value for Google (cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork). If you were using AdMob Mediation, then you would need to add the values for the Mediation networks that you were using. At least that is what I understand based on:

**REASON 1**

This was also asked and answered in the [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers forum](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/U0dcmvZWk3Q).
The question is:

> hi,
>
> We have the app with  google mobile ads SDK and didn't see any third
> buyer for this So we are confused that from the link:
> https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#skadnetwork it's said
> "includes SKAdNetworkIdentifier values for Google
> (cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork) and select additional buyers who have
> provided these values to Google"
>
> So in this case, If our app doesn't have additional buyer, what we
> should do? For SKAdNetworkIdentifier, Could we just the google value
> (cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork) here?

The answer was:

> Hi there,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to us.
>
> With regard to your question, you can use (cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork)
> since your're only using Google product. For your question regarding
> if your app doesn't have additional buyer, as you are only using
> Google product, there's no other steps you need to do other than
> including in SKAdNetworkIdentifier values the Google
> (cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork).
>
> Regards, Google Logo   Princess Pamela Pineda Mobile Ads SDK Team

The other answer was:

> Hi there,
>
> I work with Pamela and will assist you. Mediation Partners have their
> own SKAdNetwork codes. The recommendation is to include all codes that
> may be used by an ad, meaning all sources for your ads should have
> their own code placed in your plist.
>
> Regards,
>
> Google Logo    Aryeh Baker Mobile Ads SDK Team

**REASON 2**

By looking at the AdMob Mediation documentation. For example, for [Facebook](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook?hl=en#skadnetwork_integration) it says:

> Facebook asks that you add the following SKAdNetwork identifiers to
> your project's Info.plist file:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
        <string>v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
        <string>n38lu8286q.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I had the same question :)